# Sorting a dictionary by a specific rule

Tags: python

I have a dictionary (D) of dictionarys (D1..DN). Inside of those DN are Pairs of Numbers. The result looks like this:

```
D = {1:{1: 15, 2: 20, 3: 50, 4:100},
     2:{1: 14, 2: 21, 3: 25, 4: 75},
     3:{1: 16, 2: 24, 3: 74, 4:102},
    }
```

Now, I came up with a program that compares the numpers of one line to the ones in the other and finds the ones that are close to each other. If it finds a number in line one (with key j) that belongs to a number in line two (with key k) it produces a tuple (j,k). The program does this for every line except the last, so in the end we will have (N-1)-Lists of tuples.

```
C = [[(1,1),(2,2)],
     [(1,1),(3,2),(4,3)],
    ]
```

Now what I need is this rule applied to my Dictionary D, so the keys in each line represent the information I gathered in the Program and if there is no information to fill that position with a zero. I want the result to look like this:

```
D2 = {1:{1: 15, 2: 20, 3:  0, 4: 50, 5:  0, 6:100},
      2:{1: 14, 2: 21, 3: 25, 4:  0, 5: 75, 6:  0},
      3:{1: 16, 2:  0, 3: 24, 4:  0, 5: 74, 6:102},
     }
```

I know this should be a fairly easy problem, but I have been trying for hours now and I can not get my head around this. The Problem is, that, if I find a number with no partner, I need to make placeholder zeros in all the other lines recursivly.

EDIT: You are right ofcourse, I simply forgot the keys in the dictionary D. Thank you. The Problem however remains the same.

Comment: `D` is a `set`, not a dictionary, as posted. Which would be an error as dictionaries are not hashable. You forgot the keys there.

Comment: ... or you meant a _list of dictionaries.

Comment: I think you should spend some more time explaining waht you are aiming to do.

Answer (score 1):

`D` is actually a `set` as expressed by one of the comments. To create a dictionary you need to specify a `Key` and a `value` in the following way.

```
D = {
     '1': {1: 15, 2: 20, 3: 50, 4:100},
     '2':{1: 14, 2: 21, 3: 25, 4: 75},
     '3': {1: 16, 2: 24, 3: 74, 4:102},
     }
```